# Error multiple arguments in varnum

Tags: sas

am trying is--> if varnum for &vars is less than 0 means the variables dont exist in the DS if varnum more than 0 then fail. but the error arises multiple arguments in the varnum statement.. how can code to check in a single statement that &vars macro variable which has these variables in it BRTHDTC DMDTC RFENDTC RFSTDTC are there in the ds or not..?

```
%macro drpchk (lib,dsn);
%local dsid result;
proc sql noprint;
    select distinct catx(".",libname,memname), name 
    into :DS separated by " ", :vars separated by " "
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname = upcase("&lib") and format=('YYMMDD10.');
quit;

data &dsn(keep=&vars);
set &DS;
run;
    %let dsid=%SYSFUNC(open(&dsn));
    %IF %SYSFUNC(varnum(&dsid,&vars)) < 0 %THEN %DO;
result=pass;
else result=fail;
end;
run;
%mend;
%drp_chk(dtelib,dte);
```

Comment: Don't use macro logic in your data step, your mixing macro and data step logic here.

Comment: That's not the way to do it. Varnum will never resolve correctly and there isn't a function to do it at once. This doesn't make sense. Why not create the summary from the DICTIONARY table directly, no need to work with the dataset.

Comment: How do you want to represent the result of checking if those specific variables exist? Do you require that ALL of them exist of than NONE of them exist or something in between?

Comment: @Tom i just need to check if all of them exist or not in the data set & if &vars<0 they don't exist so result=pass and &vars>0 variable exist so result =fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the goal of this process is, but perhaps it would help to simplify what the macro is doing. Let's just make a macro that will take an input dataset and a list of variable names and return the list of those variables that it found in that dataset.

```
%macro drpchk(dsn,varlist,mvar=droplist);
%local lib qlist ;
%if not %symexist(&mvar) %then %global &mvar ;
%if %index(&dsn,.) %then %let lib=%upcase(%scan(&dsn,1,.));
%else %let lib=WORK ;
%let dsn=%upcase(%scan(&dsn,-1,.));
%let qlist="%sysfunc(tranwrd(%sysfunc(compbl(%upcase(&varlist))),%str( )," "))";
%let &mvar=;
proc sql noprint;
  select name
    into :&mvar separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname = "&lib"
    and memname= "&dsn"
    and upcase(name) in (&qlist)
  ;
quit;
%mend;
```

You could then use that list to generate a drop statement.

```
data test;
  length SUBJID $10 BRTHDTC DMDTC RFENDTC RFSTDTC 8;
run;

%drpchk(test,BRTHDTC DMDTC RFENDTC RFSTDTC);
data want ;
  set test;
  drop &droplist;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of a long way to generate the list of datasets with variables present. This program looks at ALL variables, to restrict it to a select list, see the line of code to be modified via the comments.

The method is similar but no macros.

```
/*Generate fake data to work with*/
data class1;
    set sashelp.class;
    drop age sex;
run;

data class2;
    set sashelp.class;
    drop weight height;
run;

data class3;
    set sashelp.class;
    Order=1;
run;

data class4;
    set sashelp.class;
    keep name;
run;

data class5;
    set sashelp.class;
run;

/*Extract metadata from dictionary tables*/
proc sql noprint;
    create table column_list as select memname, libname, name, type, 1 as count 
        from dictionary.columns where libname='WORK' and memname like 'CLASS%'
        /*ADD THE VARIABLE LIST HERE*/
        order by memname, name;
quit;

/*Transpose results to a more user friendly format*/
proc transpose data=column_list out=flipped;
    by memname;
    id name;
    idlabel name;
    var count;
run;

/*Format output*/
data want;
    retain memname;
    set flipped;
    array class(*) _NUMERIC_;

    do i=1 to dim(class);

        if class(i)=. then
            class(i)=0;
    end;
    All_Variables=sum(of _numeric_)-I;
    DROP I _NAME_;
run;
```